# Android Log in using created account from SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created an app that you will be directed to `SignIn` and a `SignUp` clickable `TextView` if they don't have an account page

SignUp

- They will be asked some information about them
- Info will be added to `SQLite Database`
- One of the information will be their Username
- After succesful Signing up they will be directed to `SignIn` page

Sign in

- One of the information will be their Username
- Password
- And a Log In `Button` that will direct them to their profile after successful Log in

**Log In class(with Register button for new user)**

```
public class Login extends Fragment {

TextView tvRegister;
EditText user, pass;
Button btnLogin;
SQLController dbcon;

public Login() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_in, container, false);

    // Log in
    user = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // Sign up
    tvRegister = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegDoc);
    tvRegister.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tvRegister.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Registration());
            ft.commit();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // btnLogin onClickListener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
            dbcon.open();

            Log.v("LoginDetails", user.getText().toString() + "../.."
                    + pass.getText().toString());
            Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new UserProfile());
                ft.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // dismiss dialog
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
    }

}
```

**Sign up class**

```
public class Registration extends Fragment {

TextView tvRegID, tvCode, tvLastname, tvFirstname,
        tvCardID, tvRegion, tvLocation, tvContact, sMon, sTue, sWed, sThu,
        sFri, sSat, sSun;
EditText editRegID, editCode, editLastname, editFirstname, editPass,
        editConpass, editCardID, editLocation, editContact;
TimePicker tpMon, tpTue, tpWed, tpThu, tpFri, tpSat, tpSun;
Spinner spinSpecialty, spinRegion;
Button btnReg, btnMon, btnTue, btnWed, btnThu, btnFri, btnSat, btnSun;
SQLController dbcon;


public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

public Registration() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_page, container, false);

    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    // TextView
    tvRegID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDocRegID);
    tvCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDocCode);
    tvLastname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLastname);
    tvFirstname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstname);
    tvCardID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCardID);
    tvRegion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegion);
    tvLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    tvContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);

    // TimePicker
    tpMon = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    tpMon.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpTue = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
    tpTue.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpWed = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker3);
    tpWed.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpThu = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker4);
    tpThu.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpFri = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker5);
    tpFri.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpSat = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker6);
    tpSat.setIs24HourView(false);
    tpSun = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker7);
    tpSun.setIs24HourView(false);

    // EditText
    editRegID = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editRegID);
    editCode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCode);
    editPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    editConpass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editConfirmPassword);
    editLastname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLastname);
    editFirstname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFirstname);
    editCardID = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCardID);
    editLocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
    editContact = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editContact);

    // Spinner
    spinRegion = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinRegion);

    btnReg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
            dbcon.open();

            String regid = editRegID.getText().toString();
            String code = editCode.getText().toString();
            String firstname = editFirstname.getText().toString();
            String lastname = editLastname.getText().toString();
            String card_id = editCardID.getText().toString();
            String region = spinRegion.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String location = editLocation.getText().toString();
            String contact = editContact.getText().toString();
            String pass = editPass.getText().toString();
            String conpass = editConpass.getText().toString();

            String monday = (tpMon.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12 : tpMon
                    .getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpMon.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpMon.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpMon
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String tuesday = (tpTue.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12 : tpTue
                    .getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpTue.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpTue.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpWed
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String wednesday = (tpWed.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12
                    : tpWed.getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpWed.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpWed.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpWed
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String thursday = (tpThu.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12
                    : tpThu.getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpThu.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpThu.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpThu
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String friday = (tpFri.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12 : tpFri
                    .getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpFri.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpFri.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpFri
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String saturday = (tpSat.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12
                    : tpSat.getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpSat.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpSat.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpSat
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");
            String sunday = (tpSun.getCurrentHour() % 12 == 0 ? 12 : tpSun
                    .getCurrentHour() % 12)
                    + " : "
                    + tpSun.getCurrentMinute()
                    + " "
                    + ((tpSun.getCurrentHour() > 11 && tpSun
                            .getCurrentHour() < 24) ? "PM" : "AM");

            dbcon.insertData(regid, code, firstname,
                    lastname, card_id, region, location,
                    contact, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday,
                    saturday, sunday, pass, conpass);




            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Login());
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
    }
}
```

**SQLite DB Helper**

```
public class SqlDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "user_table";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// DOC INFO TABLE
public static final String _id = "_id";
public static final String COL_REG_ID = "reg_id";
public static final String COL_CODE = "code";
public static final String COL_FNAME = "firstname";
public static final String COL_LNAME = "lastname";
public static final String COL_CARD_ID = "card_id";
public static final String COL_REGION = "region";
public static final String COL_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String COL_CONTACT = "contact";
public static final String SCHED_MON = "monday";
public static final String SCHED_TUE = "tuesday";
public static final String SCHED_WED = "wednesday";
public static final String SCHED_THU = "thursday";
public static final String SCHED_FRI = "friday";
public static final String SCHED_SAT = "saturday";
public static final String SCHED_SUN = "sunday";
public static final String COL_PASS = "password";
public static final String COL_CONPASS = "confirm_password";
private static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + _id
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_REG_ID
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_CARD_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_REGION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LOCATION
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_MON
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_TUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_WED
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_THU + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_FRI
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SUN
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONPASS
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public SqlDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**SQLite Controller**

```
public class SQLController {

private SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new SqlDbHelper(context);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}


public void insertData(String regid, String code, String firstname,
        String lastname, String card_id, String region,
        String location, String contact, String monday, String tuesday,
        String wednesday, String thursday, String friday, String saturday,
        String sunday, String pass, String conpass) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, regid);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CODE, code);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, firstname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, lastname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID, card_id);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, region);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, location);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, contact);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_MON, monday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_TUE, tuesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_WED, wednesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_THU, thursday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_FRI, friday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SAT, saturday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SUN, sunday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONPASS, conpass);
    database.insert(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { SqlDbHelper._id,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_CODE,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME,
             SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_MON,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_TUE, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_WED,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_THU, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_FRI,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SAT, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SUN,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS, SqlDbHelper.COL_CONPASS, };
    Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public Cursor getuser_information(String code, String password){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(true, SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_CODE, SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS } , SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE + "='" + code.toString().toLowerCase()+"' and "+ SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS+"='"+password+"'", null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }
    else
    return cursor;

    }        
}
```

**In Login class I did fetching data from db to log in**

Problem:
- I want if the user log in account will stay until the user log it out

(working on UserProfile class layout yet there will be buttons for `Edit Account` `Log Out` )

Comment: You can use shared preferences to store the login information... and on click of logout button just clear the preferences refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted a UserProfile.class, but here is a solution for you:

When your user logs in, you save the required information about the logged in user in SharedPrefences. Now if your App starts again, and sees that there is a User logged in in your SharedPreferences, it automatically returns to his session. If the user logs out, the SharedPreferences entries will be deleted.

Comment: yeah sorry i'm still doing my UserProfile class .. Thank you

Comment: no problem. keep it going and write if you need some more help

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in (i.e after authentication) store the `Username` and `Password` in `SharedPreference`. The values will be present even if the user closes the application.

So when the application is launched you need to check whether the `SharedPreference` has any values. If it has then directly navigate him to `Profile` otherwise ask him to `SignIn / SignUp`.

When the user logs out then `clear` the values present in `SharedPreference`.

For more details [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)